# AngularJS: Post nested JSON parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to post nested JSON parameters to my rails app. It works with **jquery**:

```
$.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
                url : 'https://example.com/users/sign_in.json',                                
                data : {
                    user : {
                        email : $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                        password : $('input[name="password"]').val()
                    }
                }
            }).success(...
```

But how does it work with **AngularJS**? Posting non-nested parameters works:

```
$http({ method: 'POST', 
            url: 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in.json',
            data: {email: $scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password}
            }).success(...
```

But how do I post nested parameters? Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: it should work the same way. what happens when you try to post it with the user{} object?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Your angular example isn't nested, its a simple object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples are actually different, I.E in your jquery one you have a `user` json object, but you don't in your angular one, you're just giving `email` and `password` and haven't actually wrapped them in a `user`

Have you tried changing this:

```
data: {email: $scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password}
```

for this:

```
 data: { user : { email: $scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead Data use params. I hope it helps

```
 $http({
                method: 'POST', 
                url: 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in.json',
                params: {email: $scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password }  

  }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
```

Comment: My JSON should look sth like: {user:{email:"me@mail.com", password: "secret"}}. But it looks like: {email: "me@mail.com", password: "secret"}

Comment: params is used for 'GET' methods and data is used for 'POST' methods